# IIS / MainEnable bindings configuration query

Tags: iis, bindings

This is my situation. I have a server which I want to run web and mail services on. I am running Windows 7 Professional with IIS 7.5 and MailEnable

The web side is up and running, as is the mail, separately.

Currently, IIS serves any request on port 80 and MailEnable (webmail) serves any request on port 8080, but what I want is to set it up so the user does not need to use a different port number, so either:

1) I add a sub-domain such as mail.mydomain.com within the bindings to make this work (I haven't succeeded in doing this yet).

OR

2) I have a folder such as www.mydomain.com/mail which then points to the web version of MailEnable.

Just to clarify...

At the moment:

Any request to www.mydomain.com is pointed to my default website within IIS
Any request to www.mydomain.com:8080 is pointed to the MailEnable website within IIS.

I have setup mail.mydomain.com but have so far failed to set up the bindings correctly within IIS to point the mail request to the correct website (MailEnable) within IIS.

I know I can have more than one website running on port 80 in IIS and that I need to use bindings, but so far I have not managed to do it.

Any pointers as to how I need to set this up?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In IIS right-click your MailEnable site.
- Select *Edit Bindings...*
- Highlight and Edit the existing binding(s).
- Set the "Port" to 80.
- Set the "Host name" to `mail.mydomain.com`.

[image]

Now any requests for "mail.mydomain.com" on port 80 will be directed to that site, all other (non-bound) host requests will be sent to the default site.

Comment: Thanks, I will check again, but I'm sure I have tried that, I'll report back!

Comment: Yes, that worked, damn I thought I'd tried everything and there it is, so simple! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. :)